# Uncaught Error: Cannot find a responsive size for a container of width=0px and data-ad-format=auto

Tags: adsense

I have a jquery mobile footer where I am showing a responsive adsense ad and getting the following:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find a responsive size for a container of width=0px and data-ad-format=auto
```

The container where I have the ad looks like:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false"></div>
```

and has dimensions of 320px by 50px.

An ad is showing in the space even though I am getting the error described above. Has anyone else seen this? Your feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

For others who get this error

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
}, 200);
```

init ad after page loaded.

Comment: In the ad code snippet you get from Google replace the adsbygoogle line with this snippet. Fixed my problem. Make sure it's in the script tags.

Comment: i believe this is against Adsense ToS. You can't modify the code.

Answer (score 3):

Better way than using of timeout is using of window.onload:

```
window.onload = function() {
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Error is caused by setting display:none to footer section. This footer sits in an overlay which is called at appropriate moments. Adsense seems to be treating it as width=0px when style for the div container is set to display:none.

Answer (score 0):

set enclosed < div > or page element css property width to 100%

example .place{width:100%}

avoid {width:auto}

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is:

```
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({})
```

But you still have to remove that function from the code generated by Google.

Answer (score 0):

```
var prev_handler = window.onload;
window.onload = function () {
    if (prev_handler) {
        prev_handler();
    }
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
};
```

this code works for me nice with multiple ad blocks