# Where do I put the adsense code for my MVC app

Tags: adsense

I just signed up for Adsense and I received the Adsense code. However, I have no idea where to put it for my MVC app. In my `_layout.cshtml` file, I have the following div section:

```
<div id="bodyContentDiv" class="container body-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="bodyDiv" class="col-sm-11">
                @RenderBody()

                <footer>
                    <hr />
                </footer>
            </div>
            <div id="advertisementDiv" class="col-sm-1" style="height: 850px; border-left: 1px solid; border-color: lightgray">
                <br />
                <br />
                <p class="text-muted">
                    Sponsors & Links
                </p>
                <br/>

                <a id="fatbirderAdLink" href="http://www.xxxxxx.com/"><img src="~/Advertising/Fatbirder.png" title="Fatbirder"></a>
                <hr class="advertising"/>
                <a id="birdAndDineAdLink" href="http://www.xxxxx.com/"><img src="~/Advertising/BirdAndDine.png" title="Watch birds and enjoy good food"></a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'd like the Adsense ad to appear in the div with an id of `advertisementId` just below the a tag with an id of `birdAndDineAdLink`. But I don't know how to get it to appear there, or even if I can.

I actually did try and paste the code below the 'birdAndDineAdLink' div but I got the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find a responsive size for a container of
>   width=118px and data-ad-format=auto

So I assumed I was doing something wrong.

I chose the Responsive adsense ad type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just past the code below the tag

```
<a id="birdAndDineAdLink" href="http://www.xxxxx.com/"><img src="~/Advertising/BirdAndDine.png" title="Watch birds and enjoy good food"></a>
<!-- PASTE ADSENSE BELOW -->
```

Comment: I actually tried that before posting this question but when I did, I got this error: Uncaught Error: Cannot find a responsive size for a container of width=118px and data-ad-format=auto

Comment: Looks like thats an error message from Google, saying they cannot find a responsive ad of width 118px. What is the width of `advertisementDiv`? Did you raise it with Google?

Comment: The advertisementDiv is 148px x 850px

Comment: Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237164/uncaught-error-cannot-find-a-responsive-size-for-a-container-of-width-0px-and-d

Comment: I've tried about every variation from that link you provided and I'm still getting the error. May have to contact Google.

Comment: can you include the CSS for `advertisementDiv`?

Comment: I think I may have gotten it to work. At least the error is gone. But no ad is displaying. I guess this isn't unusual since it can take a couple hours for an ad to appear. If it turns out to be resolved, I'll post the solution.